# Save InDesign-File under new name

Tags: save, adobe-indesign

I'm struggeling with a quite simple task. I try to save an existing InDesign file under a new file name (fyi: the file name of a xml file), but save() doesn't really stores the file and save() also closes the current file (which seems to be the new file name at that point).

Any ideas?

```
/* remove file-ending of the xml-file */
var _selectedXmlFileName = mSelectedXmlFile.name;
var _newName = _selectedXmlFileName.substr(0, _selectedXmlFileName.lastIndexOf('.'));

var _newFile = File(mInDesignSample.filePath + "/" + _newName + ".indd");

mInDesignFile = mInDesignSample.save(_newFile);        

mInDesignSample.close(SaveOptions.NO);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code above should work for you, i did a quick test with static values and it worked. Also if you comment out the last line of your code the new file will not be closed but only saved under the new name. For your reference you can look at the code snippet below that i used to test with static values, the precondition required to run this is, to have a saved InDesign document open.

```
var mSelectedXmlFile = new File("C:\\abc\\RC.xml")  //Change the path to one present on your machine
var mInDesignSample = app.activeDocument;

var _selectedXmlFileName = mSelectedXmlFile.name;
var _newName = _selectedXmlFileName.substr(0, _selectedXmlFileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
var _newFile = File(mInDesignSample.filePath + "/" + _newName + ".indd");
mInDesignFile = mInDesignSample.save(_newFile);
//mInDesignSample.close(SaveOptions.NO);        //Uncomment of you want to close the INDD file after saving it under the new name
```

If this static snippet works for you then i recommend that you debug your code in the workflow to see the values of the variables you are using, my guess is that some value is not of the right type or missing.

Thanks,

Manan